# Webdatarocks - TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Tags: webdatarocks

When I press the arrow keyboard keys with the cursor in a cell focused in the pivot, I got this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4ELv.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems like an issue in WebDataRocks. Hopefully, the WebDataRocks team will fix it in their next release.